# Java EOF file exception

Tags: java, jetty, eof

Do you have you any idea why this error is generated?

Error :-

> (org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Closed) org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Closed at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:325) at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75).

The code that cause the error is below :-

```
try {
    chain.doFilter(request, wrappedResponse);
    wrappedResponse.flushBuffer();
} finally {
    byte[] bytes = wrappedResponse.getCopy();
    if (wrappedResponse.getContentType() != null && wrappedResponse.getContentType().contains("text/html")) {
        if (bytes.length > 0) {
            String out = new String(bytes);
            out = out.replace(
                "</head>", "Hello</head>");

            response.getOutputStream().write(out.getBytes());
        }
    } else {
        //line         
        response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your server maybe not running `or` you're supplying a wrong **IP** `or` wrong **PORT** of the server `or` your server is not accessible.

Comment: It cant be because for some requests works :)

Answer (score 0):

This is common.

The client closed the connection before the entire response was received.

Some examples: long connections, mobile connections, flaky connections, or even browsers that close the tab or navigate away before the response is received fully.).

The servlet saw this as a EOF Exception during `OutputStream.write()` because there's nothing to write to anymore on that connection.